# laravel 7 insert array of objects to db

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

this is my data

```
answers: [
{text: "dsfdsfjds", correct: "false"}
{text: "asjdkjsa", correct: "true"}
{text: "sadasdsad", correct: "false"}
}
```

what I have tried

```
$answers[] = $request->answers;
        $question = Question::create([
            'question' => $request->question,
            'date' => $request->date
        ]);
        if($question) {
            foreach($answers as $ans) {
                $anss = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $question->id,
                    'text' => $ans->correct,
                    'correct' => $ans->correct,
                ]);
            }
        }
```

I get this error

```
Trying to get property 'correct' of non-object"
```

Please guide me how to insert data to db.

Comment: did you `dump` `$ans` to see what type it is?

Comment: you are using array with key, in loop use $answer as $key => $value

Comment: var_dump($ans);  also use this $ans['correct'] instead of $ans->correct

Comment: `dump($ans)` `var_dump($ans)`

Comment: dd($request->answers); and please add it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Trying to get property 'correct' of non-object"`

try to do in this way

```
$answers = $request->answers;
        $question = Question::create([
            'question' => $request->question,
            'date' => $request->date
        ]);
        if($question) {
            foreach($answers as $ans) {
                $anss = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $question->id,
                    'text' => $ans['text'],
                    'correct' => $ans['correct'],
                ]);
            }
        }
```

i just changed this `$answer[]` to `$answer` and used an array not object

Answer (score 0):

i guess your problem is in this line:

```
$answers[] = $request->answers;
```

remove brackets and try again:

```
$answers = $request->answers;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description I assume that answers is an array of json object. You should decode json object to get access to its property. Add this at the beginning of the foreach loop

```
$json_decoded_answer = json_decode($ans);
```

and then you can do this

```
$anss = Answer::create([
                'question_id' => $question->id,
                'text' => $json_decoded_answer->correct,
                'correct' => $json_decoded_answer->correct,
            ]);
```